# Excel vba -get ActiveX Control checkbox when event handler is triggered

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel spreadsheet that is separated into different sections with named ranges.  I want to hide a named range when a checkbox is clicked.  I can do this for one checkbox, but I would like to have a single function that can hide the appropriate section based on the calling checkbox.  I was planning on calling that function from the event_handlers for when the checkboxes are clicked, and to pass the checkbox as an argument.

Is there a way to access the checkbox object that calls the event handler?

This works:

```
Sub chkDogsInContest_Click()

    ActiveSheet.Names("DogsInContest").RefersToRange.EntireRow.Hidden = Not chkMemberData.Value

End Sub
```

But this is what I would like to do:

```
Sub chkDogsInContest_Click()

    Module1.Show_Hide_Section (<calling checkbox>)

End Sub
```

These functions are defined in a different module:

```
'The format for the the names of the checkbox controls is
'CHECKBOX_NAME_PREFIX + <name>
'where "name" is also the name of the associated Named Range

Public Const CHECKBOX_NAME_PREFIX As String = "chk"


Public Function CheckName_To_SectionName(ByRef strCheckName As String)

    CheckName_To_SectionName = Mid(strCheckName, CHECKBOX_NAME_PREFIX.Length() + 1)

End Function


Public Sub Show_Hide_Section(ByRef chkBox As CheckBox)

    ActiveSheet.Names(CheckName_To_SectionName(chkBox.Name())).RefersTo.EntireRow.Hidden = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using regular (Active-X) checkboxes on a normal worksheet, then your best bet is to create a Click event for each sub, then call one routine for the Hide with the parameter of the checkbox name, like:

```
Private Sub chkCheckBox1_Click()

    If chkCheckBox1.Value = True Then
        Call RangeHide("CheckBox1")
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub RangeHide(rangetohide As String)

    Range(rangetohide).EntireRow.Hidden = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I ended up doing.  I wish there was a way to do it where I could have the association between the checkbox and the range as part of a data structure and not hardcoded into each Click event function.
Additionally, I was trying to make use of the built-in data structures so I wouldn't duplicate Excel's object model by creating my own.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is to create another class that has a checkbox object as a part of it and declare that object "WithEvents"  Then I can create a method chkBox_clicked() that will be called whenever any checkbox that is a member of that class is clicked.  I can also store the range within the object.

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx

Has more info...  Great site btw for excel VBA.

EDIT: This does not work.  See my comment below.

Comment: This doesn't work, apparently.  I get an error that says Object does not source automation events.  According to "help", 


"An object must provide a default source interface so that you can write event procedures for its events. This error has the following causes and solutions:

You tried to write an event procedure for an event of an object, but that event isn't available outside the object. 
See your object's documentation for suggestions on less direct ways to deal with the event you are interested in."

This happens when I create an object
    
    Public WithEvents chkBox As CheckBox